Does the FOCAL language allow breaking out of a FOR loop?
I don't have an interpreter handy to try this out.  I'm wondering whether FOCAL allows the use of  IF inside a FOR line to break out of the loop.
Would something like the following code run, or is it not allowed ?
1.1 FOR x = 1,1,10; SET y(x) = x+4;  IF(fabs(x-5))  10, 2 

(since the value will never be negative, the line-10 is a dummy placeholder)
